# Schengen Visa through French embassy

Tags: schengen, nigeria

I want to apply for schengen Visa through French embassy in Nigeria. I have a valid UK Visa and have gotten prior to this one. I also have been to Russia a couple times and have a valid Visa.

For both Visa applications I stated that I'm married under the native customs and laws of Nigeria (traditional wedding) and included photos from my traditional wedding.

Schengen application specifically requests for the marriage certificate, I guess from court wedding, which I don't have. Is it ok to include the pictures as I did for my other visas or would it disqualify me?

Note: the wedding is relevant as proof of ties to the country.

Comment: Why is the marriage even relevant to your visa application?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Proof of ties to home country?

Comment: Yes the marriage is to show proof of ties. I also have a job and can provide evidence of employment.

Comment: Marriage pictures are not proof of marriage. How do you prove that you are married when you are in Nigeria?

Comment: I am voting to close until @JuanJimenez 's comment is addressed.